# Python xml: encode numeric character references in hex form

Tags: python, xml, lxml, character-reference

I have a number of scripts which get external data and update parts of xml files.

I use lxml in my python script and it saves character references in decimal notation, for example:

```
$ cat input.xml
<data>
  <record text="&#x41f;&#x440;&#x438;&#x432;&#x435;&#x442;">
  </record>
</data> 

$ python
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.parse("input.xml")
>>> tree.write("out.xml")

$ cat out.xml
<data>
  <record text="&#1055;&#1088;&#1080;&#1074;&#1077;&#1090;">
  </record>
</data>
```

While other scripts use hex form: `<record text="&#x41f;&#x440;&#x438;&#x432;&#x435;&#x442;">` and so there are endless series of changes in git for these files even if there are no actual changes.

How can I tell lxml to save character references in hex form (`&#x41f;`) in a python script?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the code you write the XML files.

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank I've added code sample and input/output xml files

Comment: Typing your question into a well-known search engine lead me to [this](https://answers.launchpad.net/lxml/+question/61584) – the exact same question, asked 9 years ago. The solution proposed is to post-process a Unicode version of your XML. ...

Comment: .. although I entirely agree with that answerer's initial advice ".. It's always bad style to make applications depend on a specific XML
serialisation done by a specific tool. That's exactly what canonical XML
(C14N) was designed for."  (scoder, 2009-02-19)

Comment: @usr2564301 application doesn't depend but git depends on actual serialisation. One day I will change current scheme but right now I have to support current scripts mess :(

Comment: Fedor, I fully understand :P Would the suggested solution work for you, and can you write it by yourself? (If you can, by all means do post it as an answer. If you want to use it but can't, I'll have a look.)